# Gulp 4 async-done error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "time" argument must be an instance of Array. Received null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gulp

Setting up local dev on an existing project. Had to update to Gulp 4 to maintain other dependencies. Went through gulpfile.js and changed task formatting. Here's a typical task in my current gulpfile:

```
async function images() {
  return gulp
    .src('assets/img/**/*')
    .pipe(newer('assets/build/img'))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/build/img'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
}

gulp.task(images);
```

A package called `async-done` is throwing this error when I run any task: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "time" argument must be an instance of Array. Received null`

Has anyone run into this while updating to Gulp 4?

Comment: what versions of those plugins are you using?

Comment: Which plugins do you mean?

Comment: my assumption is that `newer`, `imagemin` are gulp plugins